# Dependencia de variable de una estructura C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, estructuras, dependencias

Muy buenas!! A ver si me podéis orientar en el problema que estoy teniendo. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
sys1.model.T=1;     
sys1.model.gam="";
sys1.model.R=1;
sys1.model.Z=1;
sys1.model.D="";
sys1.model.C=1;
sys1.model.S="";
sys1.model.p="3.1176, 4.1959";
sys1.p="3.1176, 4.1959";
sys1.model.Q=pow(10,p(0));
sys1.model.H=pow(10,p(1));
double yes=llikfast(p,sys1,0, 0);
```

sys1 es la estructura de entrada que he definido para mi llikfast. Luego esta función llikfast la meto dentro de otra función de búsqueda de mínimos (lbfgs de Optimlib). El problema es que parece ser que pierdo la dependencia de p, y quiero que se mantenga para poder introducir estructuras como sys1 diferentes aplicables a mi código. Quiero decir, con el código actual mi búsqueda de mínimos no funciona, en cambio, si las variables que dependen de p las meto dentro del código del llikfast si que funcionan.

Llikfast es una función tipo double,basada en el filtro de Kalman para realizar una prediccón, con cuatro entradas que devuelve un valor:

double llikfast(vec p,sys sys1, int exact, int nfor);

P es un vector de los valores iniciales del sistema, y OptimLib es una librería para la optimización de sistemas, la cual necesita una forma concreta de declaración de funciones:

```
double llikfast_ev(const vec& p, vec* grad_out, void* opt_data){
double obj_ev=llikfast(p,sys1,0,0);
cout<<"obj_ev"<<obj_ev<<endl;
int nPar=p.n_elem;
int g;
vec p0(nPar);
double inc=1e-6;
double obj_value0;
if (grad_out) {
    for(g=0; g<nPar; g++){
        p0=p;
        p0(g)=p(g)+inc;
        obj_value0=llikfast(p0, sys1, 0, 0);

        (*grad_out)(g) = (obj_value0-obj_ev)/inc;
     }

        (*grad_out).print("que estamos liando");
}
return obj_ev;
```

}

En esta función se define el gradiente y la salida de la función a analizar, (opt_data son parámetros adicionales). Al utilizar los comandos de Optimlib para optimizar cualquier función, la función empieza a iterar cambiando los valores de p, de los valores iniciales, y a su vez cambiando los valores del sistema sys1 que dependen de p. El problema reside en que solo estoy consiguiendo que esto funcione si declaro el sistema dentro del llikfast. Adjunto en resumen el código del llikfast:

```
    double llikfast(vec p,sys sys1, int exact, int nfor){

RQRt=sys1.model.R*as_scalar(sys1.model.Q)*sys1.model.R.t();  
CHCt=sys1.model.C*sys1.model.H*sys1.model.C.t();

}
```

Es simplemente para mostrar la dependencia. Estos valores del sistema se utilizan durante la función. Cuando declaro estos valores del sistema dentro de la función, puedo aplicar la optimización ya que mantiene la dependencia a los valores de p (sys1.model.Q=pow(10,p(0))).

Espero haberme explicado mejor ahora. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: No se lo que es likfast ni Optimlib ni `p`, tal y como está redactada la pregunta es imposible responderla.

Comment: Llevas razón, es que tampoco querías extender mucho la pregunta y quería que fuese mas o menos concreta. Amplío información.